# MOSFET as a Switch with 26 V Circuit

Tags: mosfet

I'm pretty green with electronics and I've encountered a situation I need some help on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've created a circuit wherein I am inserting a logic-level MOSFET (FQP30N06L ([data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQP30N06L-D.pdf))) in place of a mechanical switch. Assume I cannot change anything about the other components other than inserting a different type of switch (ie, I can't rewire what is being switched, etc).

In testing the wiring with a 5V circuit with an LED on it across drain and source everything works fine. Connecting the gate to low turns it off, connecting to 3.3V turns it on. Fine.

However, when trying it with my actual load the MOSFET is always on and no combination of pull down resistors and other techniques seem to ever turn it off. What am I doing wrong here? Connecting the GATE to ground does not turn it off. I'm posting a picture of the breadboard that reproduces the problem. Wiring is as follows:

The wire I am interrupting carries 26V @ 30mA.

- Gate to +3.3v (to turn on) or GND (to turn off)
- Drain to +26V
- Source connects to the positive side of the motor.

For clarity (I hope) I've attached a sketch of the circuit I've tried previously and a picture of the breadboard wired up in the most simple way, without all the pull down resistors and jazz.

Some details:
1. The circuit I am replacing is a switch on the positive side of a motor. Assume I cannot change anything about the way the motor is wired.
2. I am currently able to accomplish this no problem with a relay -- I just am doing this to see if I can accomplish the same thing with a (cheaper) MOSFET -- switching 26V DC just doesn't seem like it should require a mechanical relay. Maybe I am wrong and it overwhelms the MOSFET?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Move the FET to the other side of the motor. Easy mistake to make, probably one of the most commonly made mistakes on here.

Comment: If the FET is always on, it's damaged or you have the drain and source reversed.  With the FET in the high side you will need a voltage above the 26V rail to turn it on, the max threshold is 2.5V, so 26V plus 5V should be applied to the gate to turn the FET on.  If you move the FET to the low side as @Hearth said it will be much easier.

Comment: @Hearth -- Unfortunately I cannot move it to the negative side of the motor. The switch I am replacing switched on the positive side and the negative side is not accessible. In my LED arrangement, I indeed put it on the negative side and it works as expected. Is there anything I can do to make a MOSFET work in this arrangement?

Comment: @JohnD -- In the case that I cannot do this, do you have any suggestions? I've tried switching around the drain and the source, but it has no effect -- the circuit stays on.

Comment: @jsinglet Use a PFET instead of an NFET, but the easiest option for you is probably to use a SSR.

Comment: Yep, @jsinglet has the right answer, find a PFET with a -30V Vgs rating or use a Vgs clamp circuit so as not to exceed the max Vgs.  But a SSR may be easier for you.  If you MUST use an N channel FET you'll need to develop a voltage higher than the 26V rail to drive the gate.

Comment: One way to develop an isolated higher Vgs for an NFET is a photovoltaic optocoupler designed for solid state relays.  An example part here: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83469/vom1271t.pdf switching isn't fast, but for an on/off switch it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Also, put a diode in parallel to your motor.